# Missing tracepoint_private.h when compile OSX

Tags: macos, grand-central-dispatch

I miss tracepoint_private.h file when I try to compile libdispatch for EIcapitan https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch

Does anyone has that file?
The error message I got is bellow:

../os/voucher_activity_private.h:27:10: fatal error:  'firehose/tracepoint_private.h' file not found

Comment: @Chen I'm having the same issue with High Sierra. Have you ever solved this?